# Which one is used more in America- muddle (up) or jumble (up)?

Tags: american-english, word-usage

Merriam Webster  shows them both as appearing in the bottom 40% in terms of usage.
Ngrams (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Jumble%2C+muddle&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CJumble%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuddle%3B%2Cc0) shows muddle as being a cut above jumble, but longman says muddle is especially used in British English. 
How is it in practice?

Comment: You're doing a case sensitive search that compares "Jumble" (capitalized) with "muddle" (not capitalized). You'll get more interesting results once you check the "case insensitive search" box.

Comment: You're right. jumble tops muddle now, but muddle up still has quite an edge over jumble up. It makes it even more perplexing

Comment: Don't forget "mix up" which is the clear winner vs jumble up and muddle up https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jumble+up%2Cmuddle+up%2Cmix+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjumble%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuddle%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmix%20up%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Note that the two do not mean the same thing.

Comment: Note that the Ngram search was *muddled*, not *jumbled*.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a subjective question, my evidence will be anecdotal. I live in the American Midwest, and I tend to hear the expression "muddle up" far more commonly than "jumble up."

They also are not used in the same context, now that I think about it. "Jumble up" is used in the context of words, or word choice. For example: "I jumbled up those two words." I have not really heard it used in any other context.